# Recent data supported by media report, not by peer-reviewed article?

Tags: citations, peer-review, online-resource, research-proposal

In the letter of intent for the dissertation proposal, the student reports data about the number of minority hires for x-number of program positions in the upcoming season. The source for the data is a sports newscast from February 2020; the season starts in September 2020.

The chair wanted a peer-reviewed article (not the newscast) for this data.

We (the student and I) have been unsuccessful in finding peer-reviewed articles for this data. Presumably (because we can't think of any other reason), such an article or article is elusive because the hiring event is so recent.

The recent data is truly relevant to the study.

What is an acceptable way for this dilemma to be reconciled? Initial thoughts are to cite more than one news source.

Note: This is a no-hurt feelings zone. If the question needs to be rephrased to comply with stackexchange guidelines, then ok. And if that is the case, then please give guidance.

Comment: Can you or the student write an article, using the data from the newscast, submit it for publication, and get it peer-reviewed in time to be cited in the student's dissertation? (Crazy requirements deserve crazy solutions.)

Comment: Wow. Truly crazy idea that might work under different circumstances, but not this one. The letter of intent is for the proposal, not for the final study. Need to get the proposal approved so that the study can proceed.

Comment: Having seen all too often how journalists make/have errors in data (deliberate or otherwise), the chair is absolutely correct in wanting verification of the quality of the data. So get it peer reviewed or check the data with the institutions themselves.

Comment: How about contacting the news source about their data sources?

Comment: The data is likely not from research; it sounds like it's internal to the organization; so why would it be in a peer reviewed report?

Answer (score 0):

There are cases of course where a non-peer reviewed source is the authoritative source for a particular piece of information. I'd do my level best to track down if they have the raw data (including requesting it) but personally, if that's the best source available, it's the best source available.

I'd consider that preferable to ignoring data that exists in the world because it's from the "wrong sort of people".

Comment: Being the best source available does not make it scientifically valid, however, especially in statistics. Proper data collection is a huge issue.

Comment: What if the text was qualified to read something like this, "The season starts in August 2020; as of February 2020, there are an estimated [insert number here] minority hires (media source 1, media source 2, media source 3)."  So that phrase would be used for the proposal.